# Oracle SQL Developer: Trigger

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Hello PL/SQL Experts!!

Do you know how can I use the value 'Batman' in

```
INSERT INTO SUPERHEROES VALUES ('Batman');
```

so I can have the below output

```
1 row inserted.
```

You added Batman

when I run a trigger function? I used the statement below but it does not shows Batman. Thank you in advance! (NOTE: I'm just starting learning sql)

This is a code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_SUPERHEROES
BEFORE INSERT ON SUPERHEROES
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
  V_USER  VARCHAR(20);
  SH_NAME VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN`enter code here`
  SELECT USER INTO V_USER FROM DUAL;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YOU JUST ADDED NEW RECORD ' ||SH_NAME);
END;
```

Comment: formatting code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `:new.sh_name`.

`:old` contains the old record state, `:new` contains the new record state in a `for each row` trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! In addition to that, would it be possible to add IF or exists condition if that :new.sh_name already exists on the superheroes table? What I aiming is before it insert into the superheroes table, it will check first if it is already existing. Else, it will not be inserted on the table

Comment: "it will check first if it is already existing" Don't use a trigger for that, add a unique constraint or primary key to the table instead, It's the proper way to do things.